# Stumbling over syntax-quote-unsplicing, template variables, and ellipses in syntax-case

Tags: macros, scheme, racket

What I want to be able to do is transform e.g.

```
(define count-suits (symbol-map-function hearts diamonds clubs spades))
```

into

```
(define count-suits (λ (#:hearts hearts
                        #:diamonds diamonds
                        #:clubs clubs
                        #:spades spades)
                       (make-hash (cons 'hearts hearts)
                                  (cons 'diamonds diamonds)
                                  (cons 'clubs clubs)
                                  (cons 'spades spades))))
```

I have the body of the lambda working with

```
(define-syntax (generate-symbol-map stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    ((gen...map enumerations ...)
     #'(make-hash (cons (quote enumerations) enumerations) ...))))
```

but I'm having a devil of a time generating

```
(λ (#:hearts hearts
    #:diamonds diamonds
    #:clubs clubs
    #:spades spades)
```

This is what I have so far

```
;; e.g. (weave '(1 3 5 7) '(2 4 6 8)) = '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8)
;; tested, works.
(define-for-syntax (weave list1 list2)
  (cond ((empty? list1) list2)
        ((empty? list2) list1)
        (else (list* (car list1)
                     (car list2)
                     (weave (cdr list1)
                            (cdr list2))))))

(define-syntax (symbol-map-function stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    ((sym...ion symbols ...)
     ; What I'm trying to do here is splice the result of weaving the keywords,
     ; generated by format-id, with the symbols themselves, e.g. in the case of
     ; (symbol-map-function foo bar baz):
     ;   #`(λ (#,@(weave '(#:foo #:bar #:baz) '(foo bar baz)))
     ;   --> #`(λ (#,@'(#:foo foo #:bar bar #:baz baz))
     ;   --> #`(λ (#:foo foo #:bar bar #:baz baz)
     ; I am using syntax-unquote-splicing because I am in syntax-quasiquote and the
     ; result of the expression is a list that I want to be spliced into the arguments.
     #`(λ (#,@(weave (list (syntax-e (format-id #'symbols
                                                "#:~a"
                                                (syntax-e #'symbols))) ...)
                     (list #'(symbols ...))))
          (generate-symbol-map symbols ...)))))
```

`(list (syntax-e (format-id #'symbols "#:~a" (syntax-e #'symbols))) ...)` is meant to result in

```
(list (syntax-e (format-id #'foo "#:~a" (syntax-e #'foo)))
      (syntax-e (format-id #'bar "#:~a" (syntax-e #'bar)))
      (syntax-e (format-id #'baz "#:~a" (syntax-e #'baz))))
```

but I'm told I'm missing ellipses after #'symbols. I've tried playing around with the code in different ways, but not with any real purpose or insight, and I haven't stumbled into anything that works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `...` cannot appear outside of a template, which means they must appear inside the `#'` part that precedes `symbols`. You can write `#'(symbols ...)` but not `#'symbols ...`.

After this, you will probably want to use [`syntax->list`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/stxops.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._syntax-~3elist%29%29), which turns your syntax object into a list of syntax objects.

Also, you cannot use [`format-id`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/syntax-util.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket/syntax..rkt%29._format-id%29%29) to generate keywords, because `format-id` will enforce the result to be a symbol, and will this enclose the generated id within pipes:

```
> (require racket/syntax)
> (format-id #'here "#:~a" 'auie)
#<syntax |#:auie|>
```

So you need to use [`syntax->datum`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/stxops.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._syntax-~3edatum%29%29), [`symbol->string`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/symbols.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._symbol-~3estring%29%29), and then [`string->keyword`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/keywords.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._string-~3ekeyword%29%29) to do what you want here.

Here is a working example:

```
#lang racket
(require (for-syntax racket/syntax racket/list))

(define-syntax (foo stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(_ (sym ...) body ...)
     (with-syntax ([kws (flatten
                         (map (λ(k)
                                (list
                                 (string->keyword
                                  (symbol->string 
                                   (syntax->datum k)))
                                 k))
                              (syntax->list #'(sym ...))))]
                   )
       #'(λ kws body ...))]))

; Test:
((foo (aa bb)
     (list aa bb))
 #:bb 'bbb
 #:aa 'aaa)
; -> '(aaa bbb)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working implementation of `symbol-map-function`:

```
(require (for-syntax racket/list))
(define-syntax (symbol-map-function stx)
  (define (id->keyword id)
    (datum->syntax id (string->keyword (symbol->string (syntax-e id)))))
  (syntax-case stx ()
    ((_ id ...)
     (andmap identifier? (syntax->list #'(id ...)))
     (with-syntax ((lambda-list (append-map (lambda (id)
                                              (list (id->keyword id) id))
                                            (syntax->list #'(id ...)))))
       #'(lambda lambda-list
           (make-hash `((id . ,id) ...)))))))
```

I wish I know a better way to assemble the lambda list than using `append-map`; improvements welcome. :-)